# CORS error in Browser in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, jakarta-ee, cors

Hello Developers community,
I am accessing RESTful API (written in Spring Hibernate) from Angular 6 client. When I run the Angular layer from my local, I keep getting CORS this error:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:///SpringDemoSecurity/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."
I have added Allow-Access-* headers in my response from Java layer but no help. I can see these headers in my response from postman application. I can not get rid of these errors from my browser.

Followed many threads on stack overflow and elsewhere to add all headers in request and response objects and checked their presence using Postman REST Client application but no use. Java Layer is AWS EC2 Instance while Angular is running on local.

Below is the Java code snippet in my Filter class:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "864000");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type,authorization,token");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
// For HTTP OPTIONS verb/method reply with ACCEPTED status code -- per CORS handshake
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
            return;
        }
```

I can not figure this out. Tried many things on stack overflow.
Any help on this is highly appreciated.
- Swati

Comment: please follow this tutorial https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

After receiving OPTIONS methoud, you are currently replying with a HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, which stands for 202 response code. You need to send a 200 code, (HttpServletResponse.SC_OK). Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy technique for this in angular 6. You have to create a **proxyconfig.json** file in the root of the angular app. You can follow this video- [**CORS in Angular 6**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1MUmTjYKH8)

Or it can be solved in back-end also during API creation.

Answer (score -1):

the CORS origin is a blocked browser and there is nothing to do on backend to allow this. There are 2 ways to avoid:

1) If you are using json, then try using JSONP

2) (what I did here) Convert your backend to accept Websocket connections. the websocket allows access to another origin. The address of you backend will be as ws://localhost:4200.

I hope help :)